# Understand where total value is stored in recursive function - Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to understand where the total value is stored for example the return of this function is the int `15`. Each number from the input list is taken and added one at a time and removed from the list but I cannot see where the temp value is stored I only get the complete total?

Also regarding `return L[0] + mysum(L[1:])`if`mysum(L[1:])` stores the list how can it be added with `L[0]` and if `mysum(L[1:])` does not store the list where is the list stored is it not lost and then surely the program would not know what numbers to add next?

Code

```
def mysum(L):
    print(L) # Trace recursive levels
    if not L: # L shorter at each level
        return 0
    else:
        return L[0] + mysum(L[1:])

total = mysum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

print("Total = ", total)
```

Return

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
[2, 3, 4, 5]
[3, 4, 5]
[4, 5]
[5]
[]
Total =  15
```

Comment: The total is stored in the return value at each return statement.

Comment: It stores in stack.

Comment: Specifically, each call to `mysum` is given its own block of memory on the stack, so that one call's `L[0]` is entirely separate from another call's.

Comment: Temporary result is in `mysum(L[1:])` which is then added to `L[0]` and returned.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The intermediate running totals are never "stored" in a variable - they are passed down the call stack each time one of the recursive calls returns:

- The first recursive call to return is `mysum([])` which returns the number 0.
- After this, the recursive call `mysum([5])` returns 5 + 0 = 5.
- After this the recursive call `mysum([4,5])` returns 4 + 5 = 9.
- Then the recursive call `mysum([3,4,5])` returns 3 + 9 = 12.
- Then `mysum([2,3,4,5])` returns 2 + 12 = 14.
- Then finally, the original non-recursive call `mysum([1,2,3,4,5])` returns 1 + 14 = 15.

I have [an interactive demo](https://werp.site/cs-toys/recursion.html) which shows how some recursive functions are computed step-by-step using a call stack. It may help you to understand how recursive functions are executed.

Answer (score 1):

The value is "stored" using the fact that before returning an expression, you have to calculate both sides.

In your example, on the first call the last "return" will be "return 1 + mysum([2, 3, 4, 5])", then mysum will be evaluated, it will be evaluated to "return 2 + mysum([3, 4, 5])".

Finally, when you've reached the end of the list, mysum return 0, so it will be "return 1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 0".